# Orthogonal Trajectories in Differential Equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, orthogonality

I need to find the orthogonal trajectory of:

> $$x^2+y^2=Cx$$

Here is my attempt:

$
\begin{align}
2x+2yy'&=c\\
x+yy'&=c\\
yy'&=c-x\\
y'&=\frac {c-x} y \text{    <- DE of original}\\
y'&=-\frac y {c-x} \text{    <- DE of ot}\\
\frac {dy}{dx}&=-\frac y {c-x}  \\
\int \frac {dy}{y}&=-\int \frac {dx} {c-x}  \\
-\ln|y|&=-\ln|c-x|+\ln|c| \\
\ln|y|&=\ln|c-x|-\ln|c| \\
|y|&=|c-x|-|c| \\
y&=K-x-c \\
\end{align}
$

[image]

I attached a picture with my work and was hoping for someone to help me check whether it is right.

Comment: why do you have $\ln K$?

Comment: Maria check for mistakes please..

Comment: You miss the very idea of the question. There is a whole **family** of curves with different $C$, and you have to find the DE that matches them all.

Answer (score -1):

Given equation: $$\ x^2 + y^2 = cx$$ Differentiating it wrt$\ x$ we get:$$\ 2x + 2y(\frac{dy}{dx}) = c$$Now replace $\ \frac{dy}{dx}$ by$\ \frac{-dx}{dy}$ to get differential equation of orthogonal trajectory which is:$$\ \frac{-2dx}{c-2x} = \frac{dy}{y}$$Now integrate both sides:$$\int \frac{-2dx}{c-2x} = \int \frac{dy}{y}$$$$\  ln|c-2x| = lny + lnk$$$$\ ln|c-2x| = ln|ky|$$$$\ y = \frac{c-2x}{k}$$
where$\ k$ is any constant.

Comment: Maria you did some calculation mistakes . Match with solution posted above .